# How to perform predicate on UIbutton array which includes tag value of each buttons and i want to match the tag of each button 

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nspredicate

I have an array of `UIbutton` objects. What I want to do is that I want to match each UIbutton object's `tag` value. For that I want to write a predicate. What should be the predicate for this?

Comment: Do care to provide more description regarding your question.

Comment: yes next time i will do , i am newbie to stackoverflow sorry :(

Comment: you just edit this question......

Comment: @SandipArmal  question edited !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 UIButton *btnSelected = [self.view  viewWithTag:1];
 NSArray* filteredArray = [[yourButtonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag  == %d",[btnSelected tag]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I like block predicates for non-Core Data predicates, I think it's a little more clear exactly what it's evaluating.

```
NSInteger tagToSearchFor = 13;
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(UIButton *button, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return (button.tag == tagToSearchFor);
}];
```